# jquery- manipulating ctrl-z and ctrl-y with textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When im writing on chrome for example (got to work on all browsers) on the textarea in my site, and im pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, its deleting everything i wrote until the last "/n". Is there any way that i could make javascript save texts, so when a user will press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> its will go to the last point when javascript saved the data?

For example, i would love to save the data every time a user click on backspace or a button that changes the textarea. its preety similar to the undo, redo buttons on stackoverflow.

Some kind of a string list isnt good for me, im looking for a built javascript/jquery way of doing that, if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look in this library

http://dmauro.github.io/Keypress/

It's allow you to detect all input, so basically you can store it on any letter typed, or at least save the text in the textarea everytime a special key is pressed.

It's also really easy to detect combo.

Hope that's help

Comment: You can catch each typed letter and saved them, then handle the ctrl+z event and remove one letter or one word from the saved text.